# MMO market (subscribe model, not play for free)

Tags: mmo, monetization, statistics

What mmo games do you know (play) with WoW-like monetization-subscribing (not play 4 free)?
And how many active gamers playing them and what cost of each of them?

Thank you!

Comment: Read the [FAQ](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq) please.

Comment: This question is not constructive. It doesn't have a correct answer. This is a Q/A site, not a forum or polling site.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at http://www.mmorpg.com/gamelist.cfm - it lists about hundred games with their payment models.

The number of active subscribers is usually hard to find out. The only source is usually the marketing department of each game, which often polishes the number.